# How to trigger handleChange event from inside the function using jquery and react?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using fullcalendar-scheduler plugin for following calendar. Currently I have integrated it with react and rails. In order to change the positions of the element I have called the select function from inside viewRender function of fullCalendar instead of render on react. On this case how do we change state when select option is changed and fetch the data again from api?

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import axios from "axios";

class TestCalendar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cars: [],
      events: [],
      price: [],
      selectDates: [],
      startDate: moment(),
      endDate: moment().add(3, 'years')
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    axios.get('/api/v1/test_calendars?date_from=' + this.state.startDate.format(), { headers: headers })
    .then(res => {
      const cars = res.data;
      this.setState({ cars });
    });

    axios.get('/api/v1/test_calendars/events?date_from=' + this.state.startDate.format(), { headers: headers })
    .then(res => {
      const events = res.data;
      this.setState({ events });
    });

    axios.get('/api/v1/test_calendars/prices?date_from=' + this.state.startDate.format(), { headers: headers })
    .then(res => {
      const price = res.data;
      this.setState({ price });
    });
    this.updateEvents(this.props.hidePrice);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('componentDidUpdate');
    this.updateEvents(this.props.hidePrice);
    console.log(this.state.cars);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    $('#test_calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
  };

  handleChange(e) {
    debugger;
  }

  updateEvents(hidePrice) {
    function monthSelectList() {
      let select = '<div class="Select select-me"><select id="months-tab" class="Select-input">' +
                    '</select></div>'
      return select
    }

    function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
      var dateArray = [];
      while(startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') <= stopDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {
        dateArray.push(startDate.format('YYYY-MM'));
        startDate = startDate.add(1, 'days');
      };

      return dateArray;
    }

    $('#test_calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
    $('#test_calendar').fullCalendar({
      selectable: false,
      defaultView: 'timelineEightDays',
      defaultDate: this.props.defaultDate,
      views: {
        timelineEightDays: {
          type: 'timeline',
          duration: { days: 8 },
          slotDuration: '24:00'
        }
      },
      header: {
        left: 'prev',
        right: 'next'
      },
      viewRender: function(view, element) {
        let uniqueDates;
        $("span:contains('Cars')").empty().append(
          monthSelectList()
        );

        $("#months-tab").on("change", function() {
          let index, optionElement, month, year, goToDate;

          index = this.selectedIndex;
          optionElement = this.childNodes[index];
          month = optionElement.getAttribute("data-month");
          year = optionElement.getAttribute("data-year");
          goToDate = moment([year, (month - 1), 1]).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
          $("#test_calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', moment(goToDate));
          $("#months-tab").find("option[data-month=" + month + "][data-year=" + year + "]").prop("selected", true);
          this.handleChange.bind(this)
        });

        let dates = getDates(moment(), moment().add(3, "years"));
        uniqueDates = [...new Set(dates)];
        $('#months-tab option').remove();
        $.each(uniqueDates, function(i, date) {
          $('#months-tab').append($('<option>', {
          value: i,
          text: moment(date).format('MMMM') + " " + moment(date).format('YYYY'),
          'data-month': moment(date).format('MM'),
          'data-year': moment(date).format('YYYY'),
          }));
        });
      },
      resources: this.state.cars,
      resourceRender: function(resourceObj, labelTds, bodyTds) {
        labelTds.css('background-image', "url(" + resourceObj.header_image + ")");
        labelTds.css('background-size', "160px 88px");
        labelTds.css('background-repeat', "no-repeat");
        labelTds.css("border-bottom", "1px solid");
        labelTds.addClass('resource-render');
        labelTds.children().children().addClass("car-name");
      },
      resourceLabelText: 'Cars',
      dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view, resource) {
      },
      dayRender: function(date, cell){
        cell.addClass('dayrender');
      },
      select: function(startDate, endDate, jsEvent, view, resource) {
      },
      events: this.state.events.concat(this.state.price),
      eventRender: function(event, element, view){
      },
      schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives'
    });

    // Should stay after full component is initialized to avoid fc-unselectable class on select tag for months
    $("#months-tab").on("mousedown click", function(event){event.stopPropagation()});
    $(".prev-link").on("click", function(event){event.stopPropagation()});
    $(".next-link").on("click", function(event){event.stopPropagation()});
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div id='test_calendar'>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TestCalendar;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your onchange callback doesn't have the react component context so you cannot change the state without giving access to the proper context. One solution I may quickly suggest is to change your `updateEvents` function like bellow. I have only kept the changed code.

```
updateEvents(hidePrice) {
    let context = this;

    ... // your code

    $('#test_calendar').fullCalendar({
      ... // your code

      viewRender: function(view, element) {
        ... // your code

        $("#months-tab").on("change", function() {
          ... // your code

          // Call the handleChange with the context.
          context.handleChange.bind(context)(this); // edited here
        });

        ... // your code
    });

    ... // your code
  }
```

Then you will be able to call the setState method from the `handleChange` function.

Comment: Hey @Sazedul . I tried making the changes as you mentioned. But it does not trigger handleChange event when adding `debugger` inside it. Did I miss something here?

Comment: Sorry! My bad. I wasn't exactly calling the handleChange from the onChange. Only binded with the context. Call like this `context.handleChange.bind(context)(this);` I have updated the code a bit.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Just a quick question. Is there a way after getting into handleChange function and setting the state, could we make the componentDidMount() fetch the required data again with updated state?

Comment: No. componentDidMount() will not be called again unless the component remounts. If you need to fetch those data again then you have to do that on the handleChange function or in componentDidUpdate() function very carefully with certain condition so that it doesn't fall into infinite loop. :)

Answer (score 0):

You must be facing an issue with the `this` reference, as you are trying to access the method `handleChange` which is associated with the `component this` but you are using the normal function for `viewRender` instead you should use `arrow function`

see the updated code below, it will solve the issue,

```
updateEvents(hidePrice) {

    $('#test_calendar').fullCalendar({
        ...
        viewRender:  (view, element) => {  // convert to arrow function so, this (component instance) will be accessible inside.
        // store the reference of this (component instance).
        const $this = this;

        $("#months-tab").on("change", function (e) {
          ...
          // always bind methods in constructor.
          $this.handleChange(e);
          ...
        });
      },
        ...
    });
}
```

thanks.